# undefined variable using a shell variable in a ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, undefined

I'm fairly new to bash script and probably won't do this often. I have the below script to check latest updates at a certain location, but I'm getting:
`location: Undefined variable` and the timestamp is not retrieved successfully.

```
#!/bin/bash

servers=('x' 'y')
results=()
location="/path/to/location/"

for server in "${servers[@]}"; do   
    output=$(ssh "$server" 'find "${location}" -exec stat \{} --printf="%y\n" \; | sort -n -r | head -n 1')
    x=(${server}:${output})
    results+=(${x})
done

echo "Printing results..."
for res in "${results[@]}"; do
    echo "$res"
done
```

My goal is to print at the end:

```
x:<timestamp of last update>
y:<timestamp of last update>
```

I'm wondering what's wrong.

Comment: `/bin/sh` doesn't support arrays, btw, so `servers=('x' 'y')` can't possibly work without changing your shell to bash, ksh, or similar.

Comment: Same for `x=( ... )`.

Comment: that said, your `location` is also undefined because it's in outer single quotes, so of course it won't get expanded. The best way to fix that requires still more bash extensions incompatible with your `#!/bin/sh` shebang.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. What's a common alternative to arrays in this case?

Comment: If there were an easy and safe alternative, there wouldn't have been a need for ksh (and its derivatives such as bash) to implement arrays. :)

Comment: Also, the `printf %q` behavior leveraged in my answer to safely quote the location has no equivalent in POSIX sh either.

Comment: BTW, if you really do want an answer for `/bin/sh`, take off the `bash` tag from your question, and change the title to no longer describe it as a "bash" script.

Comment: thanks I'll try this

Comment: @alvits, sure; I'm counting that out because I don't consider restricting the range of data that can be safely handled (beyond content such as NUL that can't exist in a filename, command-line argument, etc) as, well, "safe". :)

Comment: By the way -- a "undefined variable" error is actually somewhat unusual to be default behavior. Any chance your `/etc/rc` file, or `~/.rc`, or `~/.bashrc` &c. on the remote side might run `set -u`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem here is that `'foo "$bar"'` still has the expansion of `bar` inside of single quotes (which make the double quotes literal, as opposed to syntactic). That's not a bad thing -- literal quotes, when passed to `ssh`, can then be honored by the shell on the remote side of the ssh connection -- but it has the side effect that `$location` isn't expanded; thus, the reference to `"${location}"` makes it to the remote shell, where it's undefined.

---

The best way to generate a correctly-escaped command for either `eval` or to be passed as an argument to `ssh` is to ask the shell to do it for you. In present case, that looks a bit like this:

```
printf -v cmd1 '%q ' find "$location" -exec stat --printf='%y\n' '{}' +
ssh "$server" "$cmd1 | sort -n -r | head -n 1"
```

The pipeline components aren't included in `cmd1` because -- in escaping content to be treated as data rather than syntax -- `printf %q` would cause literal `|` characters to be passed as arguments to `find` rather than as shell directives. (This is exactly what you *want* it to do with any literal contents inside of `$location` which might otherwise be used to run as commands!).

That way, the shell itself (via the magic of `printf %q`) will be responsible for expanding variables and correctly escaping your `find` command in such a way as to ensure that content is treated as data (ie. so a `location` of `'/tmp/$(rm -rf /)'` won't delete files).

Comment: Thanks this worked.. A different question is: I'm getting only the date whereas if I run the cmd directly in the terminal I get the time as well..

Comment: Is that true even running it directly in the terminal *on the remote system*? In any event, if you want portable timestamps formatted in a way that isn't specific to the system locale settings, I'd suggest changing your format string to transfer them as epoch time, and converting from that to a proper date/time string locally.

Comment: BTW, if you have a stat with `--printf`, that's a pretty clear indicator you're targeting a system with GNU utilities, so you should have a `find` with `-exec {} +` too.

Comment: ...actually, maybe even a `find` with `-printf`, which would let you have `find` directly print the timestamps, thus no longer needing `stat`.

Comment: forgot to mention typo: `'%y\n" --> "%y\n"`